# How do I resolve this yum problem: "no repomd file"

Tags: fedora, yum, repository

I am using Fedora 20 and trying to install several software packages. e.g.

```
sudo yum install python-matplotlib
```

And get this response for *every* package I try:

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
adobe-linux-i386                                         |  951 B  00:00     
epel/i386/metalink                                       |  38 kB  00:00     
Could not parse metalink https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink repo=epel-7&arch=i386 error was 
No repomd file


One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

File /var/cache/yum/i386/20/epel/metalink.xml does not exist
```

I don't understand the suggestions enough to confidently attempt them.

I have searched the Internet for a solution and have tried this ...

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum update -y
```

... which had no effect on the problem.

and this ...

```
[Harry@localhost]~% cat /etc/fedora-release
Fedora release 20 (Heisenbug)
[Harry@localhost]~% sudo yum distro-sync --releasever=20
```

... which gave the same "no repomd file" error

Please can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fedora 20 is considered old, unsupported.  According to the [Fedora wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Releases#Old_Unsupported_Releases), that applies also to Fedora 21.

The timeline is explained in [another part of the wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_Release_Life_Cycle):

> The Fedora Project releases a new version of Fedora approximately every 6 months and provides updated packages (maintenance) to these releases for approximately 13 months. This allows users to "skip a release" while still being able to always have a system that is still receiving updates.

Fedora 20 was released in late 2013; this is mid-2016.  If you want updates, you'll have to upgrade the system.

Comment: Thanks for the information Thomas, I will upgrade to Fedora 23 and try again.